# NSLayoutManager: How to prevent creating a separate glyph for emojis

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, nslayoutmanager

I am using an `UITextView` and customised `NSLayoutManager` to draw text with a background. For this I assign an underlined `NSAttributedString` to the `UITextView` and then override the `drawUnderline` of the `NSLayoutManager` to draw the background instead of drawing the underline. This works quite well because with regular text we just get one glyph per line.

[image]

However if emojis are added to the string the `NSLayoutManager` creates a separate glyph for the emojis which then breaks the design because `drawUnderline` is called for every separate glyph range hence the backgrounds do overlap with each other then.

[image]

I tried to only draw one background per line but it turned out to be less reliable than expected. Is there any possibility to stop the NSLayoutManager from creating a separate glyph for the emojis?

I appreciate the help!